# Adding a Global Router Param with Express 4.11

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to create a global param that will be used by my Router with Express 4.11. The general function of this is that I am using `router.all('/*',function(){});` This method is creating a list of all my routes to dynamically create a navbar in a partial jade template. I can pass the list to the response but I want to not have to call this on every route method I create i.e

```
router.all('/*',function(res,req,next){
var links = [];
console.log('Being Called...');
for(var i=0; i< router.stack.length; i++) {
    var route = router.stack[i];
    if(route['route'].path !== '/*'
        && route['route'].path !=='/favicon.ico'){
        var name  = (route['route'].path !=='/')? route['route'].path.toLowerCase().replace('/','') : "Home";
        var active = (route['route'].path === url.parse(res.originalUrl).pathname)? true: false;

        links.push({
            name: name,
            path: route['route'].path,
            active: active
        });
    }
}
if(links.length > 0) {
    console.log(res.locals);
    res.set('appLinks',links);
}
next();
});
```

`/*GET home page*/`
`router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {title: 'Home', appLinks: req.appLinks});
});`

I want that appLinks to be a global param that is used by all of my routes. How do I go about this? or am I over thinking it and should just add that small line of code?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use router.all but instead place following before any router.get or .post or whatever

```
router.use(function(req,res,next){
    var links = [];

    //your code here

    res.locals.appLinks = links;

    next();
});
```

anything added to res.locals is available in views so there's no need to pass it to res.render(...)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Is there a reason as to not use router.all()?

Comment: Well, router.all serves a bit different purpose than router.use. 

router.all
router.get
router.post

these are for routing whereas 

router.use is a middleware

Well, this is how i see it anyway.

So you can actually use i think. It's just that i wouldn't :)